# Sum over multiindex

Tags: summation, permutation, index

I would like to calculate a sum over some multi-indices, that follow a specific pattern.

$$\sum\limits_{1\le i_1<i_2<...<i_k\le N} A(k,i_1, i_2, ..., i_k).$$

$A$ is a fix expression of the entire multi-index and $k$. To make the expression easier to implement one can use instead a more computer-like expression

$$\sum\limits_{1\le i_1<i_2<...<i_k\le N} A(k,i_1, i_2, ..., i_k)=\sum\limits_{i_1=1}^N\sum\limits_{i_2=i_1+1}^N\sum\limits_{i_3=i_2+1}^N...\sum\limits_{i_k=i_{k-1}+1}^NA(k,i_1, i_2, ..., i_k).$$

I could not yet find out how to implement a sequence of sums of variable length.

I tried to start with *all* permutations of $\{1,...N\}$, cut them in lengths of $k$ and restrict them to $1\le i_1<i_2<...<i_k\le N$. But my own code looks somewhat spurious and I don't trust it, since I have not as much experience in Mathematica. Especially I am not sure about the use of `Union`:

```
n = 4;
k = 3;
P = Permutations[Table[i, {i, 1, n}]];
Union[ Table[Sort[P[[j]][[1 ;; k]]], {j, 1, Length[P]}]]
```

However, I think there is a more elegant way of summing here. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Module[{n = 4, k = 3},
 Sum[a @@ Array[i, k], {i[1], 1, n}, 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{i[j], i[j - 1] + 1, n}, {j, 2, k}]]]
 ]` should get you started.

Comment: If you have some code already, please share it! This way, potential answers and comments can give a lot more relevant feedback. (It might also motivate more people to look into your problem if they see you already worked on it ;-) )

Comment: @AccidentalFT: That was exactly what i was looking for - thanks